# Проблема при копировании листа в новую книгу Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Мне необходимо через консоль Apps Script сохранить копию активного листа, как новую таблицу Google. А также сохранить копию листа, как файл `PDF`.
Вот скрипт, который я смог написать:

```
  function CopySheet() {
      var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('name1');
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().copyTo(newSpreadsheet)
      DriveApp.createFile(newSpreadsheet.getAs("application/pdf"))
}
```

Скрипт работает, однако есть проблема в том, что в новой таблице есть мой лист, и пустой лист "Лист1". Этот пустой лист также выводится в файл `PDF`.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне изменить скрипт для этой задачи?

Также возможно подскажете, как сохранять файлы не в корневой папке, а в папке по названию или `ID`?

Answer (score 1):

```
const TARGET_FOLDER_ID = "ID папки, в которую нужно сложить pdf";

function copySheet() {
  // создаем временный файл
  const newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("name 1");
  // копируем ативный лист во временный файл, называем его как в исходнике
  const activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  activeSheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName(activeSheet.getName());
  // удаляем лишний лист
  const sheet =
    newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Лист1") ||
    newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet);
  // создаеим и перемещаем pdf в указанную папку
  removeNewFile(
    DriveApp.createFile(newSpreadsheet.getAs("application/pdf")).getId()
  );
  // удаляем временный файл
  Drive.Files.remove(newSpreadsheet.getId());
}

function removeNewFile(fileId) {
  // перемещене новых файлов списания в папку
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(TARGET_FOLDER_ID);
  file.moveTo(folder);
}
```